# Can I add multiple currency prices to a product in one data upload?

Tags: pricebook, multi-currency, currency, product, pricebookentry

I am using the data uploader to add prices to a bunch of products I just created.

We work in GBP, EUR & USD; Can I use one spreadsheet to upload all currencies in one hit (standard Price) or would this need to be separate?

EUR - 13,650
GBP - 11,400
USD - 15,000

As always - appreciate any advice offered. Kind Regards, Paul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in one Data Loader operation.

One row per `currency - list price - product2Id - pricebook2Id`  You probably will need to use an Excel operation to transform your source data which is most likely one row with many columns of list prices, one per currency into the one row per currency required by Data Loader

[image]

If you are using custom pricebooks, the PricebookEntries for the standard pricebook must precede the PricebookEntries for the custom pricebooks

Comment: How is this done though? I dont have the option to map multiple currencies when inserting the data.

Comment: @PaulRogers - amended answer to be clearer. I've done what you are doing so many times that I was forgetting something implicit

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and still it will only map one ISOCurrency and therefore when I check the product after the upload there is only one price showing. which means I then have to do the upload again but map the currency to say USD then do the upload again and map GBP etc.

Comment: @PaulRogers - I edited my answer to show an example that I just did - two currencies - one upload file. Works fine. You may need to use the Edit link on your OP to post a snippet of your CSV file

Comment: Legend that worked, for some reason I was insisting in putting different currencies in different columns hence the fail. Your method works and has made my life muchos easier. Thanks

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for... 1 minor correction.. it is UseStandardPrice not UseStandardPriceBook on the Excel G column